# Confusion about for...in loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

All:

**[UPDATE problem solved] The problem I have here is:
so if I use "in", the func is the index number while using "of" the func is the function.
More detail refer to [Variables and scoping in ECMAScript 6](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-scoping.html)**

This is my first hour of ES6 study, I wonder why I can not use syntax like:

```
for(func in funcs) { }
```

In:

```
  "use strict";

  var funcs = [];
  for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
    funcs.push(function(){
      console.log(i); 
    });
  }

  let func;
  for(func in funcs){
    func();
  }
```

It always reports:

```
Uncaught TypeError: func is not a function
```

Comment: You meant `for of`? `for in` still has the same meaning as in ES5

Comment: @Bergi  Thanks, yes, that is what I should use. It turns out that  I mix the usage of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`for... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) iterates over object keys. It's been in JavaScript since day one.

I think you are confusing it with [`for... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), which is an ES6 feature for looping over [iterable objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) including Arrays.

```
for(let func of funcs){
  func();
}
```

[Babel.js REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=%0A%20%20var%20funcs%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20for(let%20i%3D0%3B%20i%3C10%3B%20i%2B%2B)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20funcs.push(function()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(i)%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20let%20func%3B%0A%20%20for(func%20of%20funcs)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20func()%3B%0A%20%20%7D)

Comment: Thanks, this is new knowledge to me! I will accept this after 7 minutes

Comment: Thanks, now I am clear the usage, so if I use "in", the func is the index number while using "of" the func is the function.

Comment: Yes, and there are some [good reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea) that you shouldn't use it for Arrays. `for... of` doesn't have the same problems.

Comment: Another confuse about this is: I read that "let" can prevent duplicated declaration of same variable, but if I put the "let" inside the for, it still work, does that means each round of loop, ES6 will create a new block to hold specific func variable in that round?

Comment: Thanks, so even the let inside the for, it only seems like declare func each loop from the format while actually it is only declared func once and keep reusing it and only difference comparing with declaration outside for loop is the place that func variable lives? But if so, this confuse me so much: why each func can have their own "i"?

Comment: Yeah, that is my confuse lies. Since every loop share the same i ( rather than another i ), why in the fun, it can show according i(0,1,2,3..9)

Comment: I've deleted comments as I think they were a little confusing - this article should clarify :-) http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-scoping.html.

Comment: Thanks I will read this.

Comment: I read that post, so if I use "let" VS "var", it will affect how JS engine treat each loop's storage space creation( if "let", then there will be multiple storage space created for specific "i" and the function defined in it ), right?

Comment: I don't know about storage space (the spec doesn't say anything about _how_ to use memory), but you can think of it as a separately bound `let` for each iteration.